# Generalization of Schur polynomials

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, polynomials

*EDIT (2018-11-05)* I am slowly making a list of symmetric functions, and generalizations available online [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/polynomialindex.htm). PDFs with overviews are available there for download.

I am making a list of generalizations of Schur polynomials and other closely related polynomials that appear in representation theory. My motivation is to eventually make a nice poster of specializations/relations between all these, and which ones have say a Cauchy identity, positive multiplicative structure constants, constitute a basis, have determinant formulation, combinatorial interpretation, etc.

So far, these are (more or less) the ones I know about, 
and I would like to know what more I have missed.

- Hall–Littlewood polynomials
- Shifted Schur polynomials
- LLT polynomials
- Quasi-symmetric Schur polynomials
- Factorial Schur polynomials
- Flagged Schur polynomials
- Double Schur polynomials
- Schubert polynomials (and double Schubert)
- Stanley symmetric functions (also known as stable Schubert polynomials)
- Key polynomials (also known as Demazure characters)
- Jack polynomials
- Macdonald polynomials (where there are non-symmetric and non-homogeneous variants)
- Schur polynomials for the symplectic and orthogonal group.
- $k$-Schur functions (defined via cores)
- Loop Schur functions
- Grothendieck polynomials ($K$-theoretical analogue of Schur polynomials)

This should be a community wiki, I guess.

EDIT: I have started making an overview but I get the feeling it should be split into two posets, (specializes/is superset of and expands positively in) since these two relations usually go in the opposite order.

[image: polynomials]

Comment: There are some listed on page 405 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol.2, that don't seem to be on your list.

Comment: There are also stable Grothendieck polynomials and dual stable Grothendieck polynomials: see http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2189.

Comment: how about multisymmetric ones, such as e.g. in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405490 ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Is there an analogue of Schur polynomials in that paper? I only see analogues of elementary and monomial symmetric functions...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: hmm, sorry, I thought I saw there something like the Cauchy identity. But perhaps I was dreaming :-)

Comment: How about the rep of the elementary Schur polynomials as cycle index polynomials (CIP--http://oeis.org/A036039) of the symmetric groups? How would the CIP and their generalizations fit into your scheme?

Comment: @TomCopeland: Sure, I think I found a reference for them: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316580900709/1-s2.0-0097316580900709-main.pdf?_tid=3f4bdc7a-e4a7-11e5-b9c2-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1457384448_66a1f92ac2c1a100f6af94fb9c3513bb

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, the link in your last comment is broken. Could you give the title and author?

Comment: @TomCopeland it could be this one https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X18303029

Comment: And that is "Quasisymmetric and Schur expansions of cycle index polynomials" by Loehra and Warrington

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment.) The elementary Schur polynomials (edit: cf. Sec. 1.5 of "[Combinatorial solutions to integrable hierarchies](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07172)" by Kazarian and Lando) are also the refined Lah partition polynomials (divided by n!) of OEIS [A130561](http://oeis.org/A130561) and so are connected by simple transformations of the defining indeterminates to the celebrated Bell partition polynomials [A036040](http://oeis.org/A036040) of the Faa di Bruno formula (refined Stirling numbers of the second kind), and the cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups (refined Stirling numbers of the first kind) of [A036039](http://oeis.org/A036039). All these partition polynomials can be generalized or restricted then generalized in different directions often by the action of differential operators or as reps of iterated differential ops to incorporate a whole slew of important polynomials, e.g., the associated Laguerre polynomials and generalized Stirling numbers and associated polynomials with numerous combinatorial interpretations.

Comment: What are the elementary Schur polynomials?

Comment: See the Carrell ref in A036039. Also the draft edits for A130561, which contains a ref to a paper by Ernst on "The history of the q-calculus and a new method." Pg. 127 of Ernst has the o.g.f. of the elem. Schur poly. : $\exp\left [\sum_{n > 0} a_n x^n  \right ] = \sum_{n \geq  0} S_n(a_1,..,a_n) x^n$

Comment: See my March 7'th comment above.